# Adding a table on crystal report using Database expert: login failed

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, ms-access-2013

I am using vb.net 2008 and access 2013 (64bit) on a windows 7 machine. I am working on crystal reports. When adding a table on a crystal report using Database Expert, it gives me this error:

> Logon Failed; Details: DAO Error code: 0xd0f[enter image description
>   here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvnuW.jpg) Source: DAO Workspace Description: Unrecognized Database
>   Format D:\Users\ojotome\Desktop\MMIS\MMIS\bin\Debug\Meal.accdb;

Screenshot included in image link above

Comment: Put some code in here;  or you will get nothing but;  downvoted my friend

Comment: Did you try to use odbc?

Comment: I tried ODBC but asks for UserID and Password when loading reports. I enter the UserID and password and could not load reports despite the fact that I entered UserID and Password when establishing a connection for the first time in database connection expert

Answer (score 0):

It is very Clear You have a wrong Username and Password to your Database While establishing to access on it.

Check Username and Password Correctly.

Comment: I tried inputting Username and password but could not connect and another error; "Can not start your application. the workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user"

Comment: Another thing I want you to know also is; 1. The open Dialog box does not show Access Database despite the fact that it is it Directory. 2. It does not show accdb but only mdb on the file type. This type of error is not there when I am using Office 2007.